# Can not connect to firebird databse file in PHP and Apache

Tags: php, firebird, firebird-3.0

I'm using Apache in remote hosting with cPanel. I need to fetch data from a Firebird database file using PHP, so I enabled "interbase" and "pdo_firebid" modules.

I execute connection to database file code, but it's not working.

```php
$dbh = new PDO('firebird:dbname=localhost:/public_html/users.fdb', 'sysdba', '123');
```

This is not working and this error appears in log:

> Failed to connect to the Firebird database: SQLSTATE[HY000]
> [335544721] Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".

Comment: This suggests that your Firebird server is not running on the same machine as Apache/PHP, or on a different port than the default 3050, or on a different IP address than 127.0.0.1 (localhost), or that the Apache/PHP cannot connect (e.g. blocked by firewall).